# How to call web service or rest api from jaspersoft Studio Proffessional?

Tags: web-services, jaspersoft-studio

I want call web service or rest API from  jaspersoft Studio Proffessional proffesional, I tired to create JSON file/XML file adapter and putted http://api.population.io:80/1.0/countries in File or url section but it's not working.

[image]

Is there any other way to call web services or rest API from jasperstudio proffessional or I can add some web service adapter to jaspersoft studio proffesional?
In my jasper studio there is not adapter which connect to web service or rest api and use them as data source.
Note: my jasperstudio version is : 6.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a local JSON file to check if it works. If not, the problem is in your JSON (or better in the expression you are using to get records out of it, or even the way you are mapping your fields).